# sleep block all threads not just one NSthreads

Tags: ios, nsthread

I'm calling sleep() on an NSThread, ( I subclassed NSThread and put a run-loop in it) 
The thing is that this sleep call is blocking all threads not just my NSThread ...

What's the best way to get around this problem?

Comment: doesn't performSelector:AfterDelay cut it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using NSThread you should use the class method `sleepForTimeInterval:`. Check [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSThread/sleepForTimeInterval%3a) the documentation.

Comment: The documentation says it blocks 'the thread', not 'all threads'.

Comment: I meant that he should use sleepForTimeInterval: and not sleep().